# Does the Class-Path in the MANIFEST.MF can only include jar Files?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest

I want to include class files in other directories, not the directory of the main class.

If I put these directories into the `Class-Path` property of `MANIFEST.MF` it doesn't work.

Why? Is there any solution except packing these classes into a jar File?

Comment: JAR File Specification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html -- See section JAR Manifest.  "Class-Path: The value of this attribute specifies the relative URLs of the extensions or libraries that this application or extension needs. URLs are separated by one or more spaces. The application or extension class loader uses the value of this attribute to construct its internal search path."

Comment: Setting the Class Path: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A trailing slash would be required as mentioned in this link:

[Class-Path Attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#classpath)

Comment: Thank you,plus,if I have lots of jar files under a same directory ,is there any solution except adding them one by one?

Comment: @scobur , we do this by using the ant build file. There, you can specify the folder where your jars are and it will be mapped in the MANIFEST.MF file.