# Logging using log4j2

Tags: maven, logging, jboss, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to change from log4j1 to log4j2. What I did:

- deleted old configuration file log4j.xml
- created new config file log4j2.xml
- created jboss-deployment-structure.xml
- edited pom

Environment: 
Wildfly 10
1 EAR
4 WAR
The web.xml isn't being used in the file. The previous log4j config log was in the EAR (only)

**Log4j2 config file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="all.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Jboss deployment structure**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <!--Use log4j.xml file instaead of using the loggin subsystem configuration -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**new maven dependencies**

```
 <!-- Apache Log4j API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Log4j SLF4J Binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Log4j Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>

        </dependency>
```

Has I said earlier I was using log4j1 with SLF4j has facade. These are the changes I've made (I'm trying to start with a simple configuration file I've found online). The file is not even created, but the console log is working just fine.

Thanks,

Comment: Where are you expecting the file? That looks like a relative path, so maybe the application doesn't have the permissions to write there.

Comment: I'm running in the localhost. I don't think I'm expecting the file. How do you suggest I should do? Something like this in the fileName: ${jboss.server.log.dir}/log/all.log . ??

Comment: You should try to change `all.log` to an absolute path where everyone has permissions like `/Users/yourname/Desktop/all.log` on Mac or `C:\users\yourname\Desktop\all.log` on Windows. I'm not 100% on the windows path being correct, but you can double check.

Comment: time I've just done your suggestion on my mac and still didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work with a webapp in JBoss 7.1.1 using the below config.

**/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml**

```
... above unchanged ...
<File name="MyFile" fileName="/Users/tima/Desktop/all.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
... below unchanged ...
```

**WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

The pom file is the same as yours.

**Test controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test1")
public class HelloWorldController {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HelloWorldController.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> printHello() {
        logger.info("entered printHello()");
        System.out.println("entered printHello() 2");

        Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        return new ResponseEntity<>(resultMap, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Results

```
$: cat ~/Desktop/all.log
2017-05-11 15:13:35.918 [http--0.0.0.0-8080-2] INFO  com.tima.controller.HelloWorldController - entered printHello()
```

Also in the server.log I can see the following:

```
15:13:35,937 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) entered printHello() 2
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use the `org.slf4j.Logger` logger, you have to add the lines below to the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**EDIT 2**

If you are using an EAR file, you can set up logging by using a common JAR that is shared across other modules / WARs in the EAR file.

In the common JAR have:

1. The `log4j-api`, `log4j-core`, `log4j-slf4j-impl` as dependencies in the `pom.xml`.
2. The `log4j2.xml` under `src/main/resources`

Have the common jar as a dependency in the WAR files. And you can remove the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file from all WAR files.

The `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file will now be located in the EAR file under `src/main/application/META-INF/`, and contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <sub-deployment name="war-1.war">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="war-2.war">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
    ...other wars here...
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

The above configuration will print from all WAR files to the same file. But you can configure the `log4j2.xml` file to print to different files based on the package name. That approach is explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719325/log4j2-xml-configuration-file-location-for-ear)

Comment: Which Logger are you using for the test? I'm using this: import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; I'm changing from log4j1 to log4j2 (log4j1 works properly)

Comment: Below the exclusions?

Comment: @Ricardo in the exclusions

Comment: Still, with problems, the file is not created. I'm using wildfly 10 can have some influence? I will try with urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2

Comment: I just tried with Wildfly 10.1.0 and it still works. Did you update the log4j2.xml file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144057/discussion-between-ricardo-and-tima).

Comment: I think I'm on the right path, but I'm still having troubles with the exclusion of the SLF4J. Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Comment: Your example works perfectly but when I try to implement it in my code it doesn't. Maybe due to other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
<Properties>
    <Property name="basePath">C:\\logs</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="${basePath}/app-info.log" filePattern="${basePath}/app-info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout   pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.howtodoinjava" level="debug" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" level="debug" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

for morw you can follow this link : -

http://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/log4j-2-xml-configuration-example/

Comment: Didn't work :( and I've copied exactly the configuration file. The console works just fine but the file is not created.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably fair better to exclude the logging subsystem in your jboss-deployment-structure.xml. I would have done this as a comment, but pasting the xml wouldn't have been pretty.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
 <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
 </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```